# How to redirect a website

Tags: macos, unix

Within the /etc/hosts file you can block traffic via

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

# Block Adobe Activation
127.0.0.1       activate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       practivate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       ereg.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       activate.wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       3dns-3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       3dns-2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       adobe-dns.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       adobe-dns-2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       adobe-dns-3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       ereg.wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       activate-sea.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       wwis-dubc1-vip60.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       activate-sjc0.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       hl2rcv.adobe.com
#127.0.0.1      reddit.com
#127.0.0.1      www.reddit.com
```

However I want to redirect these websites to another website I have online informing the user this is blocked content

Comment: Come on, support the starving Adobe executives! Don't pirate their software!

Comment: lol this is a friends computer. I would never pay the money for a mac. However, I will inform him of his eyepatch and pegleg in the post.

Comment: @bzlm: Just because you choose to block always-on "information sharing" with Adobe's servers for privacy concerns doesn't *necessarily* mean that you're pirating the software. But yes, this does look mighty suspicious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot redirect to a website per se - the only think you can try is to get the ip address the website is hosted on and if the server is set to handle the request, it will work. That means it's not going to work on shared servers that has one IP.

For more sophisticated redirect, you have to use other solution.

Comment: could you point me in the direction of other suitable or even potential solutions.

Comment: @Will For one I'm thinking leaving the localhost in place but actually serving the webpage there (possibly redirecting to real internet sites) is certainly viable. Not really sure if there is easier solution.

Comment: Ok, so allow me to throw this in as a potential, would it be possible then to set my local host to a website's url or ip?

Comment: @Will sure, just replace the ip in `127.0.0.1 localhost` with the ip to the server you've already found. Or install an actual server on localhost as I mentioned earlier and redirect where ever you want (possibly even to a web page, not just up).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting those IPs to `127.0.0.1` set them to the IP of the "Sorry, blocked" server

Comment: how can I find out a websites ip?

Comment: @Will running the `ping google.com` command (for example) will resolve dns and print the IP out. Then you may try visiting the ip via browser and see how that turns out. If it is the website you seek, you can just use it in the `hosts` file.

Comment: I guess You have the URL of the website, something like `http://my.website.com` Now now on the OSX terminal type `ping my.website.com` and note the IP address being echode. Mind though, that you can't use something like `http://my.website.com/path/to/page.html` - this sirt of redirect is not on the IP layer, but on the HTTP layer and can thus be not created by manipulating IP info.

Comment: @EugenRieck How can I tell from a url say something like www.google.com if does a redirect or not?

Comment: By trying it out in a browser?